# How would I expand the 'scope' of an existing git repository to a parent directory?

Tags: git

I have a git repository in a directory a/b/, and I want to expand this so changes to a/ and subdirectories are stored too. Is there any way to do this simply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `b` to somewhere new, make a new directory in it called `b` and `git mv` the contents into it. Now `cp` the stuff from `a` (excluding the original `b` of course) into here and `git add` them.

Comment: That works, though sadly I can't use it in my actual repository - it's actually a git repository set up inside another proprietary repository and they don't play nicely at the best of times, let alone doing something a "bit different" like this. Thanks for the answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, starting from to dir of the git repository:

```
$ mkdir b
$ git mv * b/
$ git commit  # describe that contents have moved
$ cd ..
$ mv b/* .
$ rmdir b
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move the .git directory one level up and git add -A all files. For git it will look as if the existing files moved to a subdirectory and some new files appeared.

```
cd a/b
mv .git ../
cd ..
git add -A .
git commit -m 'Move git directory one level up'
```